# Office 2019 and VSTO runtime

Tags: windows-installer, vsto, office-interop

Has anything changed with Office 2019 regarding VSTO runtime? I'm deploying my Word add-in using an MSI installer and VSTOR 2010 is already selected as a pre-requisite. The installer seems to work on Office 2016 and Office 365, but on a machine with Office 2019 Professional Plus, it tells me that VSTO 2010 Runtime is not installed and that the installer cannot continue.

[image]

Is there a change in Office 2019 in this regard?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? @dotNET

Comment: Has been a year and I don't recall what happened then. I did find [this link](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2018/11/23/support-office2019-add-in-express-net/) that may or may not be useful. It talks about Office 2019 support in Add-in Express and says there is no big change and everything should work like normal. I was not using Add-in Express though.